# Schemas validity error, This element is not expected. Expected is {}

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Let me paste codes first

xml file

```
<d:Dyspozycja   xmlns:u="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/urzadzenia" 
            xmlns:d="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/dyspozycja"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/urzadzenia urzadzenia.xsd">
<d:Sala>
    <d:NumerSali>12</d:NumerSali>
    <d:LiczbaMiejsc>1</d:LiczbaMiejsc>
    <d:Ekran>true</d:Ekran>
</d:Sala>
<d:Przechowalnia>
    <d:Rzutnik>
        <u:Rozdzielczość>Duża</u:Rozdzielczość>
        <u:ŻywotnośćLampy>10</u:ŻywotnośćLampy>
    </d:Rzutnik>
</d:Przechowalnia>
```

and first xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/dyspozycja"
        xmlns="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/dyspozycja"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        xmlns:u="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/urzadzenia">

<xsd:import schemaLocation="urzadzenia.xsd" namespace="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/urzadzenia"/>

<xsd:element name="Dyspozycja">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Sala" type="typ_list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
            <xsd:element name="Przechowalnia" type="Typ_Przechowalnia" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="DzienPoczatkowy" type="xsd:date" />
        <xsd:attribute name="DzienKoncowy" type="xsd:date" />
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="typ_list" mixed="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="NumerSali" type="xsd:integer" />
        <xsd:element name="LiczbaMiejsc" type="xsd:integer" />
        <xsd:element name="Ekran" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Typ_Przechowalnia">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Rzutnik" type="u:Typ_Rzutnik" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="4"/>
        <xsd:element name="Komputer" type="u:Typ_Komputer" maxOccurs="4"/>
        <xsd:element name="Headset" type="u:Typ_Headset" maxOccurs="2"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and second xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/urzadzenia"
        xmlns="http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/urzadzenia"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:complexType name="Typ_Rzutnik">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="Rozdzielczość" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="ŻywotnośćLampy" type="xsd:positiveInteger" />
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Typ_Komputer">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="Typ" type="Typ_TypKomputera" />
        <xsd:element name="ŻywotnośćLampy" type="xsd:positiveInteger" />
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Typ_TypKomputera">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="Desktop" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="Mobile" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="Typ_Headset">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="Słuchawki" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element name="PojemnośćBaterii" type="xsd:positiveInteger" />
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I apologize for not english names of elements I believe that it won't make things harder to understand here. When I'm trying to validate xml by `xmllint xmlfile --scheme firstxsd` I get an error `"xml:11: element rzutnik: Schemas validity error : Element '{link}rzutnik': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {link}Rzutnik )."` I don't understand it because when I change element name in xsd file for a purpose then I get an error`" element rzutnik: Schemas validity error : Element '{link}rzutnik': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {link}Rzutnik )."` So why in the first case validation doesn't see the child if in the second case validation see it but doesn't validate because of a wrong name? Sorry for my english it's not my first language I hope my problem is quite understandable.

link = http://www.inf.ug.edu.pl/dyspozycja (I can't paste more than 2 links)

Comment: I'm puzzled too. It seems to be saying that it found an element with name "rzutnik" (lower-case r) when the schema says it should be "Rzutnik" (upper-case R). But there's nothing with the name "rzutnik" (lower-case r) in the XML you have shown us.

Comment: yeah this error with lower case r appears when I change it on purpose in xml or xsd, the point is if it see `Element '{link}rzutnik': This element is not expected.` then why won't it see elements with proper names as well